# PHP code for moving the cursor using the twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, web-crawler

So I already have a script that collects the first 4999 followers ids of a twitter user using the API in xml format.  I semi understand how the cursor process works but I am confused how to implement it to loop until it gathers all the followers.  The user I am attempting to gather will take about 8 calls.  Any ideas on how to implement the cursor loop?

```
<?php
 $xmldata = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids/microsoft.xml';
 $open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
 $content = stream_get_contents($open);
 fclose($open);
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmldata);
 $cursor = $xml->next_cursor;
 $file = fopen ('output1.csv', 'w+');
fwrite($file, "User id\n\r");
 while($cursor =! 0)
 {
 foreach ($xml->ids->id as $id) 
 {
    fwrite($file, $id . ", ");
fwrite($file, "\n");


 }
 $xmldata = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml?cursor='. $cursor
.'&screeb_name=microsoft';
 ?>
```

Comment: Probably more information is required to answer your question...

Comment: Basically I am attempting to retrieve 400,000 follower IDs using the twitter API.  However, a single call only retrieves 4999 users.  I am trying to find out how to gather the rest of the followers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me take an example of Microsoft's followers (346K followers) as of now.

https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=microsoft

It fetches only 5000 user IDs, that the twitter API limit. So, you need to take the next_cursor string from the json output

next_cursor_str":"1418048755615786027"

So, your next call would be

https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=1418048755615786027&screen_name=microsoft

Keep doing this until the next_cursor is ZERO.

As you keep doing again and again, just keep storing all the ids..

Comment: i've updated with some code thanks to your response.  Would it looking something like that?

Comment: If you tell me what the error is, I can help you with it... I saw the code now.. found a syntax error... while($cursor != 0)