# Twitter API Cursor(pagination) PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I list people who do not follow me that I follow.
I want to implement [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337097/8929253) in my own code.

I use abraham's Twitter API library.

**I can take max 200 data(friends/list, followers/list). I need more.**

I can not. Can you help me? thank you.

**My Code:**

```
<?php
  require_once('twitteroauth/OAuth.php');
  require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
  $baglanti = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN, USER_TOKEN_SECRET);
  $takipEttiklerim = $baglanti->get('friends/list', ["count" => 200]);
  $takipEttiklerim = array($takipEttiklerim);
  $takipEttiklerim = json_decode(json_encode($takipEttiklerim), true);

  $takipEdenler = $baglanti->get('followers/list', ["count" => 200]);
  $takipEdenler = array($takipEdenler);
  $takipEdenler = json_decode(json_encode($takipEdenler), true);

  $array = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($takipEdenler[0]["users"]); $i++) {
      array_push($array, $takipEdenler[0]["users"][$i]["screen_name"]);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($takipEttiklerim[0]["users"]); $i++) {
      if (!in_array($takipEttiklerim[0]["users"][$i]["screen_name"], $array)) {
        echo $takipEttiklerim[0]["users"][$i]["name"];
      }
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Profile_1
Profile_2
...
Profile_200 (max)
```

Comment: Why you _can not_? is there a limit for the API?

Comment: Well you simply can't, if there is a rate limit you need to figure out a way to bypass it, which I don't advise.

Comment: What? please only use English in SO.

Comment: I edited the comment. Sorry.

Comment: Ah I see, I've never used the Twitter API. Just do what the other answer suggested or read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! This is a poorly created and old question by me. But I am answering it so that it will be useful for beginners who have such problems.

As stated in the [twitter doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-list), each query returns a new cursor. If you initialize the previous cursor you have before submitting a new query, it will return the next page.

Example response:

```json
{
"users": [
      {user-object},
      {user-object},
      {user-object}
  ],
  "previous_cursor": 0,
  "previous_cursor_str": "0",
  "next_cursor": 1333504313713126852,
  "next_cursor_str": "1333504313713126852"
}
```